# Jquery UI Slider ui.slider returns ui as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, slider

I am creating a website that is utilizing multiple jquery ui sliders. The sliders each manipulate many numbers, and those numbers add together to form total numbers. For this reason, I need to store all of the calculations of the sliders into one function. Everything is functional, except there is a bug with the slider's displayed values. If I have moved the slider up and then go to move it back down, the value will first go up one before beginning to decline. The same happens the other way around. From my research I have determined this is because I am using .slider("values", 0) instead of ui.value.

The problem I am running into is that when I change it to ui.value, the console logs that ui is undefined because it is in a different function. However, it almost has to be in a different function for it to work.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(function() {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
        });

        //Graphic Design Slider
        $(function() {
            $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
                min: 0,
                max: 50,
                value: 0,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    update();
                }
            });
        });

        //Web Development Slider
        $(function() {
            $( "#slider-range-min2" ).slider({
                min: 0,
                max: 50,
                value:0,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    update();
                }
            });
        });

        //Commercial Slider
        $(function() {
            $( "#slider-range-min3" ).slider({
                min: 0,
                max: 50,
                value:0,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    update();
                }
            });
        });

        //Sets budget input value as variable
        $("#budget").on("keyup change", function() {
            value = this.value;
            update();
            console.log(value);
        });

    });

    function update() {
        //slider functionality
        $graphicDesign = $("#slider-range-min").slider("values", 0);
        //$graphicDesign = $("#slider-range-min").val("$" + ui.value);
        $webDev = $("#slider-range-min2").slider("values", 0);
        //$webDev = $("#slider-range-min2").val("$" + ui.value);
        $commercial = $("#slider-range-min3").slider("values", 0);
        //$commercial = $("#slider-range-min3").val("$" + ui.value);
        $totalHours = $graphicDesign + $webDev + $commercial;
        $totalCost = ($graphicDesign*20) + ($webDev*30) + ($commercial*50);

        //Stores graphic design percent as variable
        $graphicDesignCalculation = $("#slider-range-min").slider("value");
        $graphicDesignCost = ($graphicDesignCalculation*20);
        $graphicDesignPerc = Math.round((($graphicDesignCost*100)/$totalCost)*10)/10;
        console.log($graphicDesignPerc);

        //Stores web development percent as variable
        $webDevelopmentCalculation = $("#slider-range-min2").slider("value");
        $webDevelopmentCost = ($webDevelopmentCalculation*30);
        $webDevelopmentPerc = Math.round((($webDevelopmentCost*100)/$totalCost)*10)/10;
        console.log($webDevelopmentPerc);

        //Stores commercial percent as variable
        $commercialCalculation = $("#slider-range-min3").slider("value");
        $commercialCost = ($commercialCalculation*50);
        $commercialPerc = Math.round((($commercialCost*100)/$totalCost)*10)/10;
        console.log($commercialPerc);

        //slider displayed values
        $("#gdhours").val($graphicDesign);
        $("#gdcost").val("$" + $graphicDesignCost);
        $("#wdhours").val($webDev);
        $("#wdcost").val("$" + $webDevelopmentCost);
        $("#chours").val($commercial);
        $("#ccost").val("$" + $commercialCost);
        $("#totalhours").val($totalHours);
        $("#totalcost").val("$" + $totalCost);
        $("#gdpercentage").val($graphicDesignPerc + "%");
        $("#wdpercentage").val($webDevelopmentPerc + "%");
        $("#cpercentage").val($commercialPerc + "%");

        //Functionality if budget is not defined
        if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
            console.log("no budget");
        }

        //Determines if within budget
        else {
            if(value >= $totalCost) {
                console.log("Under budget");
                $("#overbudget").val("$0");
                $("#overbudget").removeClass( "red" );
                $("#overbudget").addClass( "blue" );
            }
            if (value < $totalCost) {
                console.log("Over budget");
                $("#overbudget").val($totalCost - value);
                $("#overbudget").removeClass( "blue" );
                $("#overbudget").addClass( "red" );
            }
        }


        //Pie Chart 
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
        {
            title:{
                text: "Breakdown of Spending",
                veticleAlign:"top",
                horizontalAlign: "center",
                fontFamily: "Garamond",
                fontColor: "black",
            },
            legend:{
                verticalAlign: "center",
                horizontalAlign: "left",
                fontSize: 16,
                fontFamily: "Lato"
            },
            animationEnabled:false,
            theme: "theme3", 
            data: [
                {
                    type: "pie",
                    indexLabelFontFamily: "Garamond",
                    indexLabelFontSize: 20,
                    startAngle: -20,
                    showInLegend: true,
                    toolTipContent:"{y}%",
                    dataPoints: [
                        {  y: $graphicDesignPerc, legendText:"Graphic Design"},
                        {  y: $webDevelopmentPerc, legendText:"Web Development"},
                        {  y: $commercialPerc, legendText:"Commercial"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        chart.render();

        };
```

As you can tell I am fairly new to coding. I have tried moving many different ways of doing this, I just can't figure out one that keeps the functionality while also keeping everything in one function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will fix your issue, but there's two ways to get ui in the update function :

- give it to the function

  ```
  function update(ui){
      //...
  }
  ```

and then in your slide callback function

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    update(ui);
                }
```

and for your "budget" :

```
 $("#budget").on("keyup change", function() {
        value = this.value;
        update({'value':value});
        console.log(value);
    });
```

the second is to make a "global" var.

But i repeat, i'm not sure that this will fix your bug

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried it and it is still saying ui is undefined whenever I try to move a slider handle. I will keep working with it and hopefully something will work.

Comment: you have to give a parameter everytime you call update(ui), so if you call it outside the slide callback function give it {value:0}